# React Navigation V5 custom header + Typescript Error: custom property 'rightButtons' does not exist on type 'object' (router.params)

Tags: typescript, react-native, types, routes, react-navigation

I create custom header:

```
const header = ({ navigation, route, options, back }: NativeStackHeaderProps): React.ReactNode => {
    const buttons: HeaderRightButtons = route.params?.rightButtons || []
    return (...)
}
```

Typescript shows error:

> property 'rightButtons' does not exist on type 'object'

In this property Array of "buttons":

```
type HeaderRightButtons = Array<{ icon: any, action: () => void }>
```

I try to make extended type:

```
export type NativeStackHeaderPropsCustomRight =
    (NativeStackHeaderProps & {
        route: RouteProp<{params?: { rightButtons: HeaderRightButtons }}, 'params'>
    }) | NativeStackHeaderProps
```

But it doesn't solve problem.

> Property "rightButtons" does not exist in the "object | (object &
> Readonly<{ rightButtons: HeaderRightButtons; }>)" type.
> The "rightButtons" property does not exist in the "object" type.

Without `| NativeStackHeaderProps` shows error in screen declaration:

```
<Stack.Screen ... options={{
        header: headerMain,
        title: strings.titleEpochs
      }} />
```

> Type "({ navigation, route, options, back }:
> NativeStackHeaderPropsCustomRight) => React.ReactNode" cannot be
> assigned for type "(props: NativeStackHeaderProps)

How to write correct type?

Or is there a more correct way to pass an object through properties to a custom header?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error and I resolved in this way:

first of all, be sure you created the NativeStackNavigator specifying your *route* object

```
type RouteParamList = {
  myScreenName: {
    rightButtons: Array<{ icon: any, action: () => void }>
  }
}
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RouteParamList>();
```

then, declare your screen passing function to `options` property:

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="myScreenName"
  component={MyScreenComponent}
  options={({ route }) => ({
    header: (props) => <HeaderMain {...props} rightButtons={route.params.rightButtons} />,
  })}
/>
```

So, in your HeaderMain component:

```
type NativeStackHeaderPropsCustomRight = NativeStackHeaderProps & {
  rightButtons: Array<{ icon: any, action: () => void }>
};

const HeaderMain = ({ navigation, route, options, back }: NativeStackHeaderPropsCustomRight) : React.ReactNode => {
  // your component here

  const buttons: Array<{ icon: any, action: () => void }> = route.params?.rightButtons || []
  return (...)
}

export {HeaderMain}
```